# Sorting a List by the second column in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, visual-studio-2012

I am using a loop that builds a list of filenames and their creation dates:

```
Dim datelist As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Date))
Dim values As New KeyValuePair(Of String, Date)(filename, initialdate)
    If Not datelist.Contains(values) Then
         datelist.Add(values)
    End If
```

After the list is populated, I need to sort it by date before performing some other functions.
I've been looking at an orderby or sort method, but I can't figure out how to implement them correctly. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Why not a `Dictionary(Of String, Date)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sorts the original list without creating a new list (like the Linq methods) using  [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
datelist.Sort(Function(kv1, kv2) kv1.Value.CompareTo(kv2.Value))
```

Comment: For example (sorting by date): `datelist.Sort(Function(kv1, kv2) kv1.Value.CompareTo(kv2.Value))`

Comment: @Mellonjollie - [List(Of T).Sort(Comparison(Of T))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) is the `Sort` overload that Tim used, if you want to read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim sorted = (From item In datelist Order By item.Value Select item).ToList
```

should do the trick

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the code is correct, I just grabbed the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just using some simple LINQ?

```
    Dim orderedList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Date)) = datelist.OrderBy(Function(o) o.Value).ToList
```

Comment: looks like Dan-o might have gotten here first.